# How to move a file with a space in the name? (command-line)

Tags: command-line, files

The file is named `Bamboo Makeup Brush Set.jpg`

```
mv /home/said/Downloads/Bamboo Makeup Brush Set.jpg /home/said/Downloads/11/
```

doesn't work because of the spaces in the file name. How can I move this file using the command line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply do:

```
mv /home/said/Downloads/Bamboo\ Makeup\ Brush\ Set.jpg /home/said/Downloads/11/
```

Answer (score 11):

Three options:

1. Use tab completion. Type the first part of the file and hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>. If you've typed enough for it to be unique, it'll be completed. Otherwise, type more and hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> again. Or, hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> a second time to list all the possible completions.
2. Surround the name in quotes:

   ```
   mv "File with Spaces" "Other Place"
   ```
3. Use backslashes to escape the special characters:

   ```
   mv File\ with\ Spaces Other\ Place
   ```